# Does GORM support single insert with has many relationship?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have two structs having HasMany relationship like shown below:

```
type MasterJob struct {
    MasterJobID int       `gorm:"column:master_job_id;not null;AUTO_INCREMENT"`
    StartedAt   time.Time `gorm:"column:started_at;not null"`
    CompletedAt time.Time `gorm:"column:completed_at;"`
    Status      Status    `gorm:"column:status;"`
    Subjobs     []Subjob  `gorm:"foreignkey:MasterJobID"`
}

type Subjob struct {
    SubjobID     int       `gorm:"type:serial;primary_key:yes;column:subjob_id;AUTO_INCREMENT"`
    StartedAt    time.Time `gorm:"column:started_at;not null"`
    CompletedAt  time.Time `gorm:"column:completed_at;DEFAULT:nil"`
    Status       Status    `gorm:"column:status;"`
    MasterJobID  int       `gorm:"column:master_job_id;"`
}
```

I have a MasterJob object with multiple Subjobs and I am trying to save it like shown below:

```
func (r *repo) CreateJob() (int, []error) {
    subJobs := make([]models.Subjob, 0)
    job := models.Subjob{
        Status:       models.StatusInprogress,
        StartedAt:    time.Now(),
        SurveyUUID:   uuid.New(),
        FlightlineID: 1,
    }
    subJobs = append(subJobs, job)
    masterJob := &models.MasterJob{
        Status:    models.StatusInprogress,
        StartedAt: time.Now(),
        Subjobs:   subJobs,
    }
    errors := r.DB.Create(masterJob).GetErrors()
    if len(errors) > 0 {
        fmt.Println(errors)
        return -1, errors
    }
    return masterJob.MasterJobID, nil
}
```

When I try to save this object, only MasterJob data is getting saved. Am I doing this wrong or Insert like this is not supported in GORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `MasterJobID` as your primary key instead of following the conventions in gorm (`ID`), you need to mention the [Association ForeignKey](https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html#Association-ForeignKey)

In code it will look like:

```
type MasterJob struct {
    MasterJobID int       `gorm:"column:master_job_id;not null;AUTO_INCREMENT"`
    StartedAt   time.Time `gorm:"column:started_at;not null"`
    CompletedAt time.Time `gorm:"column:completed_at;"`
    Status      Status    `gorm:"column:status;"`
    Subjobs     []Subjob  `gorm:"foreignkey:MasterJobID;association_foreignkey:MasterJobID"`
}
```